# How to toggle cases of characters in a string with a one-liner?

Tags: bash, search, replace, sed

"I am Groot" should be changed to "i AM gROOT" using sed one-liner.

I've tried...

```
sed -e 's/(.*)/\L\1/' -e 's/(.*)/\U\1/'
```

..., but both expressions don't seem to run in parallel.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to SO.  Have you tried anything about which you have a question?

Comment: I've tried following
 sed -e 's/\(.*\)/\L\1/' -e 's/\(.*\)/\U\1/' 
But both expressions doesn't run in parallel i guess.

Answer (score 4):

Using sed:

```
$ echo "I am Groot" | sed 'y/ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz/abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ/'
i AM gROOT
```

`tr` is a little more compact (but [not unicode-safe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tr_(Unix))):

```
$ echo "I am Groot" | tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'
i AM gROOT
```

#### Another sed solution (requires GNU sed)

The following toggles the case with help from a character that we think will never be in a sed input line.  One possiblity would be to chose `\x00` for that character because it can never be part of a bash variable.  Another is to chose `\n` because it is never part of a sed input line.  For the following, `\n` was chosen.

All lower case characters in the input are tagged by putting a `\n` in front of them.  Then, any upper-case character is converted to lower case.  Finally, any character with a `\n` in front of it is converted to upper case:

```
$ echo "I am Groot" | sed -r 's/[[:lower:]]/\n&/g; s/[[:upper:]]/\L&/g; s/\n(.)/\U\1/g'
i AM gROOT
```

Comment: Well, that is one way to write a one-liner.
Are you sure there is no other way.
Thanks anyway though.

Comment: @sam1064max I just added to the answer another sed approach that avoids brute-force.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sesed "s/.*/echo '&'|tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'/e" file
```

Used GNU sed's evaluation command but really why not just use `tr`?

N.B. Can be used in conjunction with the `-i` option to reverse case a file in place.